# Expected an expression Array of Object

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, visual-c++

How can i solve this error?

className takes 2 parameters { string, int}
.

```
className *Object; 

Object= new className[2]; 



Object[1]= { name, id};  // ERROR
```

.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Then add it as tag to your question.

Comment: If you mean that `className` has a constructor taking two parameters, then this won't help any. When you create an array with `new[]`, each element of the array is initialized by the default constructor (which must be available). Use `std::vector<className>` instead, and its `emplace_back` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand what your code is doing:

```
int main()
{
    className *object;              // Create a pointer to className type.
    object = new className[2];      // Create an array of two className objects.
                                    // note here you are instantiating className.
                                    // This is possible because it have a default constructor.

    object[1] = { "John Doe", 1 };  // Here you're assigning new values to a existing object trough 
                                    // the assignment operator(=). As you're working with visual-c++
                                    // the compiler by default will generate the operator=() function, but 
                                    // if all conditions are not there the compiler can't generate it.
                                    // You need to add to className another constructor.

    cout << object[1].get_name() << endl;
}
```

The following class will work:

```
class className
{
public:
    className(string pname, int pid) :name(pname), id(pid){}  // New constructor.
    className(){}
    string get_name(){ return name; }
    int get_id(){ return id; }
private:
    int id;
    string name;
};
```

### On the other hand ...

You are using c++, well , **use it**.

Your main  function could be written as follow:

```
int main()
{
    vector<className> objects;              // A vector of className objects.
    objects.push_back({ "John Doe", 1 });   // Add an object to vector.
    objects.push_back({ "John Mark", 2 });  // Add another object to vector.

    cout <<  objects[0].get_name() << endl;  // Access to an object in vector.

    return 0;
}
```

If you use [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) then you don't have to worry about free the memory you have allocated with [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).